# Error trying to inherit from pandas DataFrame, when calling __init__

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio

I want to inherith from pandas DataFrame, and initialize the child class with an empty dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

class MyChildDataFrame(pd.DataFrame):

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return MyChildDataFrame

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Iniciando " + self.__class__.__name__)
        super(pd.DataFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

The last line creates an error

> **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'

when the class is created with empty data

```
x=MyChildDataFrame()
print(x)
```

I had read the [pandas documentation on inheriting from DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/extending.html#subclassing-pandas-data-structures), but it does not explains how to call the **init** method.

I also tried to pass **self** as parameter:

```
        super(pd.DataFrame, self).__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

And the line executes, but when trying to print the dataframe, but it creates a large list of error and crashes the Visual Studio debugger

When I run this code:

```
x=MyChildDataFrame()
print(x)
```

I expect this output

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

but I get errors:

[image: Screen capture]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\Packages\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_frame.py", line 688, in trace_dispatch
    if main_debugger.in_project_scope(frame.f_code.co_filename):
The program 'python.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

Answer (score 0):

```
super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

seems to work, but I don't know if I doing it correctly.